# Flex validation "This field is not required" should not appear

Tags: validation, flex4

I have addded a validation to datagrid. the validations are working fine but i am getting the additional validation "This field is required" . I dont want this validation error. I am already using the tag  requiredFiedError with a customized error. sample of the code used is :

Answer (score 0):

set the required="false"
This is the property that displays that message .
Or you can set the errorString property to empty string.